# erro de xml annotation

Tags: java, xml, annotation

estou tendo um problema quando executo meu programa e não faço ideia do que pode estar errado, fiz um programa Java com Annotations. Alguém saberia me dizer?

> [Fatal Error] :8:83: O tipo de elemento "property" deve ser seguido
>   pelas especificações do atributo, ">" ou "/>". Exception in thread
>   "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate
>   persistence units     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:84)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at Teste.main(Teste.java:10) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unexpected error parsing
>   [file:/D:/Programacao/Programas/Java/GameTeste/bin/META-INF/persistence.xml]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:294)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:84)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:80)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8;
>   columnNumber: 83; O tipo de elemento "property" deve ser seguido pelas
>   especificações do atributo, ">" ou "/>".  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:289)
>     ... 9 more

Código que estou tentando executar:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Teste {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            EntityManagerFactory entity = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
            EntityManager em = entity.createEntityManager();
            Conta c = new Conta();

            //seleciona na tabela
            //c=em.find(Conta.class, 21l);

            //seta o nome ao obj
            c.setNome("joao");
            c.setEmail("joao@email.com");
            c.setSenha("123");

            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

            tx.begin();
            em.persist(c);// insert
            //em.merge(c);//update
            //em.remove(c);//delete
            tx.commit();
            em.close();
            entity.close();

        }
}
```

Meu arquivo persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistence">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/Game" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1997" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma aspa sobrando nesse trecho:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"" />
```

Comment: Funcionou, mto obrigado mesmo :D